# c# - How to use access db without installing office

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, odbc, oledb

I am using my_database.accdb as database in my window form application...I want to install it on my client machine without installing ms office.How can i achieve this.I'm using OleDb as connector in my c# application.

Comment: already answered here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637664/connect-to-ms-access-db-accdb-without-access-database-engine-2010

Comment: If the connection string is use the Microsoft Jet then nothing need to be done.  If the connection string uses ACE (which is part of Office) then you need to download the ACE runtime driver from MSDN.

Comment: i'm using  oledb in connection string instead of Jet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**you don't** have to install ms office in the pc, all you have to do is installing Microsoft Access Database Engine. You can download it from  :
[Microsoft Access Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

According to Microsoft :

> This download will install a set of components that facilitate the
>   transfer of data between existing Microsoft Office files such as
>   Microsoft Office Access 2010 (*.mdb and *.accdb) files and Microsoft
>   Office Excel 2010 (*.xls, *.xlsx, and *.xlsb) files to other data
>   sources such as Microsoft SQL Server. Connectivity to existing text
>   files is also supported. ODBC and OLEDB drivers are installed for
>   application developers to use in developing their applications with
>   connectivity to Office file formats.
>
> The Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable is not intended:
>
> As a general replacement for Jet (If you need a general replacement
>   for Jet you should use SQL Server Express Edition). As a replacement
>   for the Jet OLEDB Provider in server-side applications. As a general
>   word processing, spreadsheet or database management system -To be used
>   as a way to create files. (You can use Microsoft Office or Office
>   automation to create the files that Microsoft Office supports.) To be
>   used by a system service or server-side program where the code will
>   run under a system account, or will deal with multiple users
>   identities concurrently, or is highly reentrant and expects stateless
>   behavior. Examples would include a program that is run from task
>   scheduler when no user is logged in, or a program called from
>   server-side web application such as ASP.NET, or a distributed
>   component running under COM+ services.

Comment: Do i need to install it on client machine or to add it as a reference in my poject?

Comment: You have to install it on the machine you want to run the app on